# Proof rearranged alternating harmonic series tends to $\frac{3s}2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The harmonic series $$s:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac1k$$  tends to $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n = \ln2$.

This rearrangement of the series is given: $$1+\frac13-\frac12+\frac15+\frac17-\frac14\pm\ldots$$ Show that this series tends to $\frac{3s}2.$

Comment: It seems as if $\frac{1}{2k}$ has a minus-sign in front of it and every $\frac{1}{2k+1}$ has a plus sign in front of it

Comment: The signs are not the issue requiring clarity, as the terms are the same as in the alternating harmonic series.  What needs to be specified is what order of terms is used in your rearrangement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\left(1+\frac13-\frac24\right)+\left(\frac15+\frac17-\frac28\right)+\left(\frac19+\frac1{11}-\frac2{12}\right)+\dots\\
&=\left(\color{#C00000}{1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14}+\color{#00A000}{\frac12-\frac14}\right)+\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18}+\color{#00A000}{\frac16-\frac18}\right)+\dots\\
&=\left(\color{#C00000}{1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18}+\dots\right)+\left(\color{#00A000}{\frac12-\frac14+\frac16-\frac18}+\dots\right)
\end{align}
$$
The sum of the red part of each group is positive, as is the sum of the green part, thus we can rearrange the red pieces and the green pieces as long as we keep them together. The red part is the normal alternating harmonic series, and the green part is one-half the normal alternating harmonic series.

Answer (score 0):

$$ A_n = 1+\frac13-\frac12+\frac15+\frac17-\frac14\pm\ldots$$

thus if you note :

$$ B_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1} $$

and

$$ C_n = \sum_{k pair}^n \frac{1}{k} $$

you have $$A_n = B_n - C_n$$

or $S_n = B_n - D_n$ where $D_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k}$

So just look for a relationship between $D_n$ and $C_n$ and there you go.

Comment: So how would one get from that to $\frac{3s}{2}$ ?$  $ $A_n$ should then be $0$ as $B_n$ and $D_n$ annihilate each other, dont they?

Comment: Cn contains less elements than Bn, so no they won't. In Cn you only sum the even numbers from 1 to n, and in Bn you sum all the odd numbers made like 2k+1 for k from 0 to n. For example, for n=5, Cn would only contain 1/2 and 1/4, and Bn would contain 1, 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9 and 1/11.

Comment: PS : for @Nate, you cannot "add or substract" equivalents. If you do, then you get weird results, for example, H2k ~ ln(2k), H2k+1 ~ ln(2k+1) so if I follow your reasoning, H2k+1 - H2k would be equivalent to ln(2k+1) - ln(2k) which limit is then 0, which means that s = 0

Answer (score 0):

Let $H_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}$

It's well known that $H_k - \ln(k) \rightarrow \gamma$ as $k$ goes to infinity.

Then a partial sum of this is: $H_{4k} - \frac{H_{2k}}{2} - \frac{H_{k}}{2}$

Which, using the approximation for $H_k$ is about $\ln(4k) - \frac{\ln(2k)}{2} - \frac{\ln(k)}{2} = \frac{\ln(2) + \ln(4)}{2} = \frac{3}{2}\ln(2) $